# Function as parameter in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

In NodeJS, I pass the first function as a parameter of the second function like this:

**The first function**

```
function sayHello(){
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

**The second function**

```
function log(func){
  func();
}
```

**Passing the first function as a parameter of the second function (1):**

```
log(sayHello)();
```

When I run the code (1) above, there is a **TypeError** and the correct way is:

```
log(sayHello); //Without a pair of brackets at the end of the line
```

Why I cannot use `log(sayHello)()` as calling a normal function?

Comment: `function log(func){
 return func;
}; log(sayHello)();`

Comment: You're not returning the function, so how can you call it?

Comment: Because `log(sayHello)` is `undefined` because `log` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: function `log` returns `undefined` ... `undefined` is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- This is very basic JS, nothing to do with node
- How do you call a function func(a) ? You type func(myArg),  not func(myArg)()!
- If I understand your problem well, you're asking why you should

  func(a)

and not

```
func(a)()
```

Pretty simple: because func(a)() does something else: it is the same as  (func(a))():

- first compute func(a)
- then take the result (return) of the function func(a)
- execute that returned object as a function

If your function does not have a return statement, it returns undefined. So you are actually doing:

```
undefined()
```

And undefined is not from a type that can be executed. So you got a typeError.

Let's have a few examples:

```js
function sayHello(){
  console.log('Hello World!');
}

function thatReturnSomeThing(){
  return 123
}

function log(myFunc){
  myFunc()
}

function logWithReturn(myFunc){
  return myFunc()
}
 
function justReturn(myFunc){
  return myFunc
}

function functionThatReturnAFunction(){
  return function() {return "lots of returns here"}
}

let a = log(sayHello)
console.log("a = " + a) // undef

let b = logWithReturn(sayHello)
console.log("b = " + b) //undef because console.log does not return anything

let c = log(thatReturnSomeThing)
console.log("c = " +c) // undef cause log does not return anything

let d =logWithReturn(thatReturnSomeThing)
console.log("d = " + d) //123 because we returned the result of thatReturnSomeThing, which as well returned something different than undef

let e = logWithReturn(functionThatReturnAFunction)
console.log("e = " + e) //we returned a function, so we log the function itself
let f = logWithReturn(functionThatReturnAFunction)() //the behaviour you actually wanted is that I think
console.log("f = " +f)
```

I let you run that code, and I hope it would help you understand the difference between function and returned object (which can be a function).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sayHello(){
  return console.log('Hello World!');
}
function log(func){ 
  return func;
};
log(sayHello)();
```

Just do it like this.Your sayHello was not returning anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it `console.log` and then return the result instead of wrapping the former in a closure?

Comment: I think that is what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `log()` is not a function that is why you are getting the Type Error. When you call `log(sayHello)`, it is calling `sayHello()` which in turn call `console.log()`. The `console.log()` is then returning the given input which is not a function.

If you want to call `log(sayHello)()`, just change the log function as given below:

```
function log(func){
  return func;
}
```